# .replaceWith replace to function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use .replaceWith to replace words to a function but it's not working I think the problem is that I didn't right the function correct but I don't know how to write it right. Can Anybody help me (it's only a miniscule.) Thank you.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js">  
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var d=new Date();
var weekday=new Array(7);
weekday[0]="Monday";
weekday[1]="Tuesday";
weekday[2]="Wednesday";
weekday[3]="Thursday";
weekday[4]="Friday";
weekday[5]="Monday";
weekday[6]="Monday";


</script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function($){  
    $('div.Shipby').replaceWith(function(){
        return $("<div>").text("Orders placed now will ship " + weekday[d.getDay()]);
    }); 
}); 

</script>

    <div class="Shipby">
         Tomorrow.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's not how `replaceWith` is working. Please [read the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/). And using `document.write` there is very very wrong.

Comment: Doesn't `document.write()` over-write the *whole* document?

Comment: @user172071 - Why would you edit your question and put the correct answer in the code there? Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Blender said, it sounds like it would be easier to just update the `text` or `html`, but if you want to use `replaceWith`, you can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function($){  
    $("div.Shipby").replaceWith(function(){
        return $("<div>").text("Orders placed now will ship " + weekday[d.getDay()]);
    }); 
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TbE6P/

Comment: I think the OP will get quite confused by this ;) But yes, this is a perfectly valid use of `.replaceWith()`.

Comment: @SLaks: Thanks, just noticed that. Fixed.

Comment: @Blender: Yes, I agree that your solution is preferable here, but figured I would show OP how to achieve this using `replaceWith` function too.

Comment: Hence my +1. The more answers the merrier!

Comment: @JamesJohnson Thank you I changed it according to your answer and it's not working (I edited my question

Answer (score 6):

Just set the `text()`:

```
$('div.Shipby').text("Orders placed now will ship " + weekday[d.getDay()]);
```

Or the `html()` if you plan on including HTML in your string:

```
$('div.Shipby').html("Orders placed now will ship " + weekday[d.getDay()]);
```

There's no need for using `document.write()`.